# download app in simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

In simultaor ,is it possible to download the app form any site?

Thanks
SKtest

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to get an app from a website. Make sure you have your mds proxy running then open the app url in the simulator web browser. This will usually be to a .jad file.

Cheers

Ray